# Can I force the browser to render DOM changes during javascript execution

Tags: javascript, browser, render, single-threaded

Is there a way to force the browser to render DOM changes during the execution of JavaScript? In the following example, only the '1000' will be displayed and I do understand that this is caused by having only a single thread processing the JavaScript executing but I was wondering if there is a way to force the browser to render each DOM change?

Example:

```
var el = document.getElementById("#fixup"),
   i;

for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
   // can i force this DOM update to the rendered?
   el.innerHTML = i.toString());
}
```

Comment: Usually by breaking execution into sequential calls to *setTimeout* or *setInterval* with a short pause (maybe even 0 since it will never actually be zero).

Comment: No, you cannot force the browser to do anything. It'll do what it wants when wants to. This includes not rendering anything (headless browser) or not executing your script at all :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with timers. Here's an example:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("fixup");
var speed = 10;
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) {
      el.innerHTML = i;
  }, speed * i, i);
}
```

```html
<div id="fixup"></div>
```

Probably not the best way though, having 1000 timers from the get go is kind of fishy.

An alternative:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("fixup");
var speed = 10, i = 0, limit = 1000;
  setTimeout(function loop() {
      el.innerHTML = i++;
      if(i <= limit){
        setTimeout(loop, speed);
        }
  }, speed);
```

```html
<div id="fixup"></div>
```

Ultimately this would be the best if you don't care for the speed at which elements are rendered:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("fixup");
var speed = 10, i = 0, limit = 1000;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
      el.innerHTML = i++;
      if(i <= limit){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }
  });
```

```html
<div id="fixup"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful feedback! How did you btw create the nice code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only supporting chrome if you call

```
alert("check the box to prevent these")
```

and it will update the DOM every time it is called but if other browsers come on it could be very annoying

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have DOM show 1-1000, then create a div object every loop and appendChild() to your el. Then instead of showing 1000, you can see 1- 1000.

inside of the forloop,

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = i;
el.appendChild(newDiv);
```

and out of the loop. 
Basically, every time it loops, you are creating a new div, assigning the value to (this) newDiv, and appending it the parent node. 
I hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the `for` performence test **[HERE](http://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4)** and you will see that the `for` loop is really fast and it can loop 1000 in ~0.135 second, so if you want to display all iteration you have to use `setTimedout()` to slowdown the operation.

Comment: Browsers will not render a new image until the current thread stops, so you need to stop processing entirely, not just slow down. ;-)

Comment: Hi @RobG, you see that my answer is helpfull or i should remove it :)